# SQL Server: Group By 30 Day Windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have developed this SQL script to do a Group By on 30 day windows:

```
SELECT MIN(id.customer_id),
       DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, e.transaction_datetime) / 30 * 30, 0) as [window_start_dt],
       DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -30, e.transaction_datetime) / 30 * 30, 0) as [window_end_dt],
FROM event as e
INNER JOIN customer_identity as id
      ON id.customer_id = e.customer_id
WHERE e.transaction_datetime BETWEEN '2003-01-06' AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY id.customer_id, 
      DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, e.transaction_datetime) / 30 * 30, 0),
      DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -30, e.transaction_datetime) / 30 * 30, 0)    
ORDER BY [window_start_dt], [window_end_dt]
```

Which results in the this:

```
customer_id,window_start_dt,window_end_dt
1,2003-01-06,2003-02-05
```

However that is not exactly the 30 day window that I want:

```
customer_id,window_start_dt,window_end_dt
1,2003-01-06,2003-02-05
```

So my issue is with the window_end_dt being off.  Currently, I am using a -30 in a DATEDIFF which is a little odd, so I would be welcome to a better way for the window_end_dt.

**EDIT:**

Here is small example dataset for the first month at least:

```
customer_id, transaction_datetime
1, 2013-02-04
1, 2013-01-21
1, 2013-01-22
1, 2013-01-27
2, 2013-02-02
2, 2013-01-08
2, 2013-01-19
2, 2013-01-21
3, 2013-02-03
3, 2013-01-15
3, 2013-01-19
```

Additionally, I would like to be able to pick an arbitrary start date for the windowing to begin if possible (not aligned to months). For example, I'd like to ideally start the windows on 2003-01-06.

**Edit:**

I made changes to reflect to the desired 2003-01-06 start date for 30 day windows and to avoid confusion. There are additional columns I am calculating in these windows. But I have removed them to keep it simple and focus on the date logic for the group bys.

Comment: Can you show original data? Are you trying to put datetimes into 30-day range blocks starting with first of month?

Comment: @Parfait, I added a sanitized version of the data for the first month just as an example and added an explanation.  I'd like like to be able to pick an arbitrary start date ideally.

Comment: @Pylander to which window belongs 2013-01-02 if first window start 2013-01-06 ?

Comment: @Mike That one would be excluded.  Sorry, probably should have left that one out to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select customer_id,
       DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,'2013-01-06',transaction_datetime)/30)*30,'2013-01-06') window_start,
       DATEADD(DAY,(DATEDIFF(DAY,'2013-01-06',transaction_datetime)/30)*30+29,'2013-01-06') window_end
  from event
 where transaction_datetime>='2013-01-06'
 group by customer_id,DATEDIFF(DAY,'2013-01-06',transaction_datetime)/30
```

test on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb9fd/3)

Comment: That is absolutely perfect and really succinct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to the ultimate goal, but you can make your running date window with a cte and then just join to it...

```
declare @startDate date = '20130101' --or perhaps select min(transaction_datetime) from your table
declare @endDate date = '20130301'   --or perhaps select max(transaction_datetime) from your table

;with dates as(
    select TheDate = @startDate
    union all
    select TheDate = dateadd(day,30,TheDate)
    from dates
    where TheDate <= @endDate
)

select
    StartWindow = TheDate 
    ,EndWindow = dateadd(day,29,TheDate)
from dates
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

So with your data.... perhaps something like this....

```
declare @table table (customer_id int, transaction_datetime datetime)
insert into @table
values
(1, '2013-01-06'),
(1, '2013-01-21'),
(1, '2013-01-22'),
(1, '2013-01-27'),
(2, '2013-01-02'),
(2, '2013-01-08'),
(2, '2013-01-19'),
(2, '2013-01-21'),
(3, '2013-01-27'),
(3, '2013-01-15'),
(3, '2013-01-19'),
(3, '2013-02-19'),    --I the following 3 rows this to show where id could fall in multiple windows
(3, '2013-03-14'),
(3, '2013-01-29')


declare @startDate date = '20130101'
declare @endDate date = (select max(transaction_datetime ) from @table)

;with dates as(
    select TheDate = @startDate
    union all
    select TheDate = dateadd(day,30,TheDate)
    from dates
    where TheDate <= @endDate
)

select distinct
    customer_id
    ,StartWindow = TheDate 
    ,EndWindow = dateadd(day,29,TheDate)
from @table
    inner join dates on 
    transaction_datetime between TheDate and dateadd(day,29,TheDate)
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| customer_id | StartWindow | EndWindow  |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|           1 | 2013-01-01  | 2013-01-30 |
|           2 | 2013-01-01  | 2013-01-30 |
|           3 | 2013-01-01  | 2013-01-30 |
|           3 | 2013-01-31  | 2013-03-01 |
|           3 | 2013-03-02  | 2013-03-31 |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```